# Specifying a null partition in a Kafka Producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

The Kafka ProducerRecord api has a few different constructors.

I want to be able to specify the topic, timestamp, key and value; but not the partition.

The closest option I can see is the following, but it forces me to specify a partition number:

`public ProducerRecord(String topic, Integer partition, Long timestamp, K key, V value)`

Is it possible to just put `null` there, to then use the standard partitioning algorithm based on the key; or will this have unwanted side-effects?

Comment: What happens when you try to give null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Kafka Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html) states:

> If a valid partition number is specified that partition will be used when sending the record. If no partition is specified but a key is present a partition will be chosen using a hash of the key. If neither key nor partition is present a partition will be assigned in a round-robin fashion.

The constructors that don't allow a partition to be specified also pass null into that parameter internally; so using null will give the expected behaviour